# how to label regression models?

Tags: sas

Im running 2 different regressions from the same dataset. I would like to name them differently to prevent confusion. How can i assign the label name

```
proc reg data = main outest = main_regression1;
model x= a b c;
run ;

proc reg data = main outest = main_regression2;
model x= a b d;
run ;

data regression_summary ;
set main_regression1 main_regression2 ;
run ;
```

[image]

Comment: Posted a solution here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/How-to-label-a-regression-model/m-p/738466

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple models within a single `proc reg` and assign each one a label.

```
proc reg data = main outest = est;
    FirstModel:  model x = a b c;
    SecondModel: model x = a b d;
run;
```

Output of `est`:

```
_MODEL_       _TYPE_    ...
FirstModel    PARMS     ...
SecondModel   PARMS     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `(in=)` option to create a temporary flag variable and then assign a value to it in another variable. For example:

```
data regression_summary ;
set main_regression1 (in=A) main_regression2 ;
if A=1 then LABEL = "Model 1";
else if A=0 then LABEL = "Model 2";
run ;
```